# solving right angled triangles and isosceles triangle:

Tags: triangles

I need help in these 2 questions please!!

1) Triangle XYZ is right angled at Y. If XY=7.2cm and YZ=5.4cm, calculate XZ.

2) The diagonal PR of a rectangle PQRS is 37cm. If PQ=35cm, find the side QR.

Comment: It would be nice,If you  had shown  your efforts

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

1) $ (XZ)^2 = (XY)^2 + (YZ) ^2 $ see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem

2) Same thing but in a rectangle. Do you think you can do it?